# Connecting Mq from Windows Server 2008 to mainframe via C#

Tags: c#, mq

I am trying to connect MQ from C# . I am able to read the message from reply queue but when I send request it is reaching as junk value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start debugging at line 237, it looks fishy. You probably made a mistake there.

Comment: 237th line  means ??

Comment: Well, I started my mind-reader-over-tcp/ip device and voila... you need to debug line 237. Maybe my device was wrong. In that case, maybe you can post your code somewhere on the internet (like right here) so we can actually *see* it and maybe help you with your problem.